# how to apply css runtime in flex 4.5?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have this style CSS file:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

global{
chrome-color: #DEEBFF;
color: #444444;
content-background-color: #FFFFFF;
symbol-color: #333333;
roll-over-color: #EBF4FF;
selection-color: #DEEBFF;
focus-color: #EEEEEE;
accent-color: #C0E3FF;}


s|Application{
background-color: #EBF4FF;
```

}

I would like to change some of these colors on runtime like chrome-color or symbol-color but cannot find these properties for setStyle.

ANy clue ?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't think you could change global styles via the setSTyle method; but you should be able to change them on the Application; which--in theory--should be inherited by every other component in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change global styles and styles for specific component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

        global
        {
            fontWeight: bold;
            fontSize: 20;
        }

    </fx:Style>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event: MouseEvent): void
            {
                styleManager.getStyleDeclaration("global").setStyle("fontSize", 12);
                styleManager.getStyleDeclaration("global").setStyle("fontWeight", "normal");
            }

            protected function button2_clickHandler(event: MouseEvent): void
            {
                myLabel.setStyle("fontSize", 100);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button click="button1_clickHandler(event)"
        label="Global" />

    <s:Button x="100 "
        click="button2_clickHandler(event)"
        label="Label" />

    <s:Label id="myLabel"
        y="50"
        text="Some text" />

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have some predefined set of changes you want at runtime then you can create multiple css files and load them at runtime. To load CSS at runtime you will have to compile css into swf, in flash builder this can be done by right clicking on the css file and selecting compile CSS to swf  or you can compile CSS to swf using

```
mxmlc filename.css
```

This command will produce filename.swf at the same directory where your css file resides. then you can load the compiled css using

```
styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("../assets/filename.swf");
```